# Extracting part of a match in a makefile rule

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile which generates a bunch of versions of an image in different places:

```
website/img/logo_256.png
website/img/logo_152.png
/tmp/logo_64.png
```

and so on (the /tmp/ generation is so I can later use those files to later generate a multiresolution `.ico`, the details of that aren't important).

I'd like a rule of the form

```
logo_%.png: ${SRC}
        convert $^ -thumbnail $*x$* $@
```

but, `$*` brings in the matched directory too, so I get a command of the form:

```
convert logo_1024.png -thumbnail /tmp/64x/tmp/64 /tmp/logo_64.png
```

which is incorrect (I need `48x48`, not `/tmp/48x/tmp/48`).

Or I can write

```
/tmp/logo_%.png: ${SRC}
        convert $^ -thumbnail $*x$* $@
website/img/logo_%.png: ${SRC}
        convert $^ -thumbnail $*x$* $@
```

which seems ugly.

I'm sure there are ways to break down and pattern match `$@` to get what  I want, but I'm not a makefile guru, so this would take some research.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Doing the "research" would be a lot less time and effort than typing that question out.  In addition to the link in Etan's post you can read http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Functions

Comment: @MadScientist Well, you clearly have some function in mind, but wouldn't it be simpler if you just said what it was. Because I read that page, and it wasn't clear which could be used to extract one wildcard out of a pattern match containing two wildcards.

Answer (score 4):

See the second half of the [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) in the GNU Make Manual:

```
Of the variables listed above, four have values that are single file names, and three have values that are lists of file names. These seven have variants that get just the file's directory name or just the file name within the directory. The variant variables' names are formed by appending ‘D’ or ‘F’, respectively. These variants are semi-obsolete in GNU make since the functions dir and notdir can be used to get a similar effect (see Functions for File Names). Note, however, that the ‘D’ variants all omit the trailing slash which always appears in the output of the dir function. Here is a table of the variants:

‘$(@D)’
    The directory part of the file name of the target, with the trailing slash removed. If the value of ‘$@’ is dir/foo.o then ‘$(@D)’ is dir. This value is . if ‘$@’ does not contain a slash.


‘$(@F)’
    The file-within-directory part of the file name of the target. If the value of ‘$@’ is dir/foo.o then ‘$(@F)’ is foo.o. ‘$(@F)’ is equivalent to ‘$(notdir $@)’.


‘$(*D)’
‘$(*F)’
    The directory part and the file-within-directory part of the stem; dir and foo in this example.


‘$(%D)’
‘$(%F)’
    The directory part and the file-within-directory part of the target archive member name. This makes sense only for archive member targets of the form archive(member) and is useful only when member may contain a directory name. (See Archive Members as Targets.)


‘$(<D)’
‘$(<F)’
    The directory part and the file-within-directory part of the first prerequisite.


‘$(^D)’
‘$(^F)’
    Lists of the directory parts and the file-within-directory parts of all prerequisites.


‘$(+D)’
‘$(+F)’
    Lists of the directory parts and the file-within-directory parts of all prerequisites, including multiple instances of duplicated prerequisites.


‘$(?D)’
‘$(?F)’
    Lists of the directory parts and the file-within-directory parts of all prerequisites that are newer than the target.
```

Edit:

As prompted by @Ian's comment I looked again and realized that this was not a complete solution. A complete solution follows.

The above `F` modifiers (and the `$(notdir)` function) will strip the path from the target filename. That's part of what is necessary.

Additional manipulation is required to extract only the numerical component from target like `/some/path/logo_64.png`.

The `$(basename)` function will strip off suffixes (as will `$(patsubst %.png,%,$@)` or `$(@:%.png=)` in a more specific fashion).

Combining those we get from `/some/path/logo_64.png` to `logo_64`. Handling things at this point depends heavily on what the data is going to look like and what assertions about it can be made. If `logo_` is a static prefix then a simple `$(patsubst logo_%,%,...)` will work (as will the matching substitution reference like before).

If that is not guaranteed but the guarantee can be made that the dimension will be the last underscore separated component then `$(lastword $(subst _, ,...))` can be used.

Comment: Fascinating, but which of these matches this need, because none of them sound like they are answering this question? And, if you are aware of one of these meeting the question, why did you post the whole list, passive aggression?

Comment: @Ian You aren't trying to "pattern match" anything here. You are trying to get the file/directory portion of the full file path of the target (or so it appeared to me, looking at it again I see what you actually wanted is more detailed than that, I shall edit, note that your original question just said "clearly wrong" and left it to the reader to determine the "correct" version). That's what the `F` modifiers (as well as the `$(notdir)` function do. And no, I pasted the list because SO guidelines instruct to quote the relevant portion of the linked page since links are unreliable long-term.

Comment: Definitely was unclear about that snippet being 'obviously incorrect', thanks, I'll edit that. Okay. I tried every single option from your list, and $(\*F) Seems to work, but I've no idea why I'd want the *file-within-directory part of the stem, e.g. "foo" from "dir/foo.c"* when I'm extracting "48" from "dir/logo_48.png" - it seemed logical I'd get "logo_48" in that case. Still it seems to work, though I don't know why.

Comment: @Ian Just for reference see the [Provide context for links](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for the SO guidelines I indicated.

Comment: The way pattern rules handle directories and stemming takes a bit of getting used to. The explanation of `$*` in [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) gives a brief example though and [How Patterns Match](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match) talks about it a little bit more.

Comment: Thanks on all fronts Etan.

Answer (score 1):

The rule needed is:

```
logo_%.png: ${SRC}
    convert $^ -thumbnail $(*F)x$(*F) $@
```

The `$(*F)`, is documented very briefly in the [Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables), as quoted in Etan's answer.

> ‘`$(*F)`’ The file-within-directory part of the stem; `foo` in this example.

The 'stem' (`$*`) is anything not explicit in the pattern. That includes the wildcard, and any implicit directories. So hence in the question it had the value `/tmp/48`, `/tmp/` from the implicit directory, and `48` from the wildcard in the pattern. So of this combined stem, I need to select just the filename part, `$(*F)`.

---

Alternatively, noting that the manual states:

> These variants are semi-obsolete in GNU make since the functions `dir` and `notdir` can be used to get a similar effect

we can instead do:

```
logo_%.png: ${SRC}
    convert $^ -thumbnail $(notdir $*)x$(notdir $*) $@
```

---

In a comment, Etan also linked to the [How Patterns Match](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match) section of the manual, to help understand how the stem is constructed. I found this useful and wanted to bubble it up into an answer.